# How to prevent viewer using app script to get values from shared google spreadsheet, especially for hidden sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

For shared spreadsheets, the permission has been set to viewer, and unticked the checkbox "Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy". However, the viewer still able to get values by using App Script, for example function:

```
function grabValues(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

I want to prevent viewer to see the data in hided sheet. It is true that viewer unable to unhide the sheet. But viewer still can access it by using the app script. May I know is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Could you just name the hidden sheets something completely unpredictable such as random numbers?

Comment: viewers still can see the name by pressing the burger button at the bottom

Comment: Ahh, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible. Consider the workaround explained [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-hide-tabs-from-specific-people-in-google-sheets/) using `=IMPORTRANGE`